# wpf custom style on textbox, combobox and checkbox

Tags: wpf, effect

i am trying to implement style at Text Box, combo box and check box as like below

http://prntscr.com/7wuiuz

please help me to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is not "Text Box, combo box and check box", there are four RadioButtons (two groups of two RadioButtons for clear) and one ComboBox on your screenshot.

You could start from learning Styles and Templates for this elements: [RadioButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296247(v=vs.95).aspx) and [ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408(v=vs.95).aspx). There are examples on this pages.